# The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I keep getting the following error on a robot. I tried updating the key and a couple other suggestions from Stack with no success.

```
sudo apt update
Get:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease [4,680 B]
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-pi-flavour-makers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-raspi2/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG F42ED6FBAB17C654 Open Robotics <info@osrfoundation.org>
Get:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:7 http://files.fictionlab.pl/repo bionic InRelease [6,476 B]
Get:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG F42ED6FBAB17C654 Open Robotics <info@osrfoundation.org>
E: Release file for http://files.fictionlab.pl/repo/dists/bionic/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 161d 13h 35min 24s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 537d 18h 12min 49s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 537d 18h 14min 23s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

I ran the following thinking this would solve it :

```
curl http://files.fictionlab.pl/repo/repo.key | sudo apt-key add
```

and it gives an OK at the end but the error posted above keeps coming back.

Please, any suggestions??

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has only a few days of support remaining. There's no point in troubleshooting, AT ALL. What you should do is a release upgrade to 20.04 at the oldest and setup your 3rd party repositories correctly. Or, better, assuming you have backups already, just install  the current LTS 22.04. PS - If you're thinking about justifying 18.04 because "ma ROS" DON'T! I've heard that excuse before and refuted it: There are new ROS versions for ANY Ubuntu LTS release.

Comment: Try this command : `curl http://repo.ros2.org/repos.key | sudo apt-key add -`

Comment: is your clock substantially off? like by years?

Comment: So, let me guess, this is a Raspberry Pi that sat in the drawer for a while? Unfortunately, _systemd-timesyncd_ is quite worthless and won’t update your time because of nonsensical reasons.

Comment: Check [this answer on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/972336) (and also all the others on this question) for a way forward.